# Upgrading an old Macbook

Tags: macbook

I just got an Intel Macbook from 2006. The original hard drive (running Tiger) still works fine, but is a bit on the small side. I'm trying to upgrade to a 320GB drive.

The local iStores claim that there's no way they can find an old Tiger disk. I figure I could at least install Ubuntu.

I've swapped out the drives, and now I'm trying to get anything to install on it, but it's not booting off any of my Ubuntu disks.

How can I get the Macbook working? Is there some way I can install something directly to the drive from a desktop? Is there a secret Vulcan pinch I need to use? Some way I can transfer the partition from the old drive to the new one?

**UPDATE:** Whenever I try to boot off any bootable CD or DVD, it reads the disk for a long time, all the while showing a white screen. Eventually it displays a folder with a question mark that flashes.

I don't have another working Mac. All my other machines are either Linux or Windows.

**UPDATE:** It turns out that the DVD drive is broken, which is why none of the installation methods worked.

I expect that once it's fixed, all will be well.

Comment: what errors do you get when booting ubuntu? (did you know about https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook?)

Comment: I've checked that page, but the boot selector doesn't appear even if I'm holding down the option key while it's booting off Ubuntu LiveCD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Carbon Copy Cloner to copy the data to the new disk. It will boot from there.

Or install either 10.6 or 10.7.

Comment: It'll have to be 10.6 - According to this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook), the MacBook1,1 can only use up to 10.6.8.